# Multithreaded logger crashes after a while and I cannot find how to solve the problem

Tags: multithreading, c++11, logging, cross-platform

**Intro**

I am working on a multithreaded cross platform logging tool which purposes logging to the console and/or a file. However the problem I have right now is only related to the console logging.

**Problem breakdown**

The way the logger works is by adding a string to a Queue of strings. In the "LogToConsole" thread there is a wait method that waits until there is a string added to the queue. When that happens it should get notified and print, then pop and unlock.

**Used variables**

```
    class Logger
    {
    public:     
        friend void LogToConsole(Logger* logger);

    private:
        std::atomic_flag _ThreadIsRunning { ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT };
        std::thread _LogThread;
        std::queue<std::string> _LogBuffer;
        std::map<std::thread::id, std::string> _ThreadName;
        std::mutex _LogMutex;
        std::mutex _AppendLock;
        std::condition_variable _LogLock;
                ...
```

**The place I add data to the buffer**

```
    template<LogSeverity severity>
    void Logger::Log(std::stringstream& message)
    {
        std::stringstream log;
        log << _ThreadName[std::this_thread::get_id()] << ":\t";
        log << message.str();

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> logAppendLock(_AppendLock);
        _LogBuffer.push(log.str());
        logAppendLock.unlock();
        _LogLock.notify_one();
    }


    template<LogSeverity severity>
    void Logger::Log(std::string message)
    {
        std::stringstream log;
        log << message.c_str();
        this->Log<severity>(log);
    }
```

The **thread** that runs in a separate loop (notice however that this method is not part of the logger class):

```
    void LogToConsole(Logger* logger)
    {
        do
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(logger->_LogMutex);
            logger->_LogLock.wait(lock);
            std::printf("%s", logger->_LogBuffer.back().c_str());
            logger->_LogBuffer.pop();
            lock.unlock();
        } while (logger->_ThreadIsRunning.test_and_set() || !logger->_LogBuffer.empty());
    }
```

**Place of thread creation**

```
    Logger::Logger() : _LogThread(), _LogBuffer(), _ThreadName(), _LogMutex()
    {
        _ThreadIsRunning.test_and_set();
        _LogThread = std::thread(LogToConsole, this);
    }
```

**Test casing**

```
        std::shared_ptr<Logger> engineLogger = std::make_shared<Logger>();
        engineLogger->SetThreadName("EngineLogger");

        std::shared_ptr<Logger> coreLogger = std::make_shared<Logger>();
        coreLogger->SetThreadName("CoreLogger");

        while(true)
        {
            engineLogger->Log<LOG_INFO>("LOG\n");
            coreLogger->Log<LOG_WARNING>("WARNING\n");
        }
```

The code seems to be working threadsafe, no dataraces etc. but it crashes after a 5-10~ seconds. I have searched if there are people that are having a similar problem, this does not seem to be the case.

[image: The exception that gets thrown after 10 seconds]

I am however not very experienced with concurrent programming, thus do not now how to handle these kind of problems very easily.

Hope someone can solve the problem or give me some advice to prevent the problem.

Comment: Can you make a [mcve]? Maybe [TSan](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSanitizer.html) can help. Data races are notoriously difficult to spot.

Comment: You should put the error message into the question as text, not as a link to a picture. Also use the debugger. It is saying that `this` is `nullptr`, meaning someone called functions on an invalid object. You can go up the call stack and might find the culprit.

Comment: The code snown above provide you with enough functionality to form a minimal complete and verifiable example. The class itself is not that much larger as the code I pasted there, if you like to see the complete class please say so, I would be glad to post it. The reason I didn't do that however is because the question form stated that I shouldn't paste complete classes/files into the question, hence I did try to follow this principle.

Comment: What they hopefully meant was not that you should not make a full example, but that you should not simply copy/paste all your code. Arguably you are already showing too much code. Ideally you replace the code with a smaller compilable example that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 0):

In `while (logger->_ThreadIsRunning.test_and_set() || !logger->_LogBuffer.empty());` you access `logger` without a mutex, so that is a data race. Also `_LogBuffer.push(log.str());` is accessed with only `_AppendLock` locked and `logger->_LogBuffer.pop()` is accessed with only `_LogMutex` locked, so that is another data race.

Data races are UB and a possible reason for the crash.

Comment: Allright, so to fix these 2 problems I need to lock the buffer check in the while loop and I need to remove 1 of the mutexes and use the other on the removed spot. Right? If so how would you make the while loop threadsafe :?

Comment: In theory you just lock every time you do an access. For the while loop that's a bit tricky, but you can set a `bool` inside the `do` block or use a lambda like `[logger]{std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(logger->_LogMutex); return logger->_ThreadIsRunning.test_and_set() || !logger->_LogBuffer.empty(); }`. In practice it's ridiculously difficult to not miss an access here or there. Using a [wrapper](https://github.com/Toeger/SCE/blob/dev/threading/thread_safe.h?ts=4) that implicitly locks can help.

Comment: Ok, I have applied the bool solution you gave me. It seems to work now. There is however one last problem: the conditional variable uses the notify_one(); method which notifies one of the threads. Resulting in sometimes wrong execution orders of the threads. This however seems to be a design flaw on my side, thus is for me to fix. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You should use the `wait` version that does a check for the condition. `logger->_LogLock.wait(lock, [&logger]{ return not logger->empty();} );`. Condition variable waits can occasionally [wake up without being signaled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup).

Comment: That did not fix the problem. The problem is not the spurious wakes because the console logs instead of "warning/log/warning/log" - "warning/warning/log/log". Hence the order of thread execution is wrong. I have however implemented your check in case that the spurious wakes might happen.

Comment: Wouldn't it solve a lot of problems, if I would create a threadsafe queue? That would mean that I can just delete all the locks in this class (except for the logging itself), because everything is handled internally.

Comment: I see. Your `LogToConsole` prints every queued string separately. To fix that you move the lock out of the loop. That way all the queued stings are printed together.

Comment: Using a threadsafe queue is definitely a good move to avoid data races. It doesn't automatically protect from an undesired access order though. If you don't want to be interrupted at certain points don't release the lock.

Comment: Moving the lock out of the loop results in a infinitely locked thread. Because both threads running the method. The ```LogToConsole``` is meant as an loop that keeps on running while the instance of the logger class exists. Thus moving the lock out of the loop results in UB.

Comment: I kinda lost track. The point is that the logger does `std::printf("%s", logger->_LogBuffer.back().c_str());` in one uninterruptable operation. Either put the whole message into one `_LogBuffer` element or print all pieces that belong together in a loop without releasing the lock.